# Creating custom thumbnail image for embedded youtube player

Tags: html

Im looking for a way to change the thumbnail image of an embedded youtube video by only using HTML code. Coding is not speciality and I would prefer not to change too much in the css or javascript files.

Thanks!
Mads

Comment: Do you have access to the video? If so --> https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431?hl=en

Comment: Nope. Thats the problem. I cant change it without downloading the video and uploading it on my own profile. And I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use JavaScript to replace an Img with the  embedded video.

Comment: Actually found a solution:
<div class="image">  
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">  
<img class="thumb" style="cursor: pointer;" src="INSERT THUMBNAIL URL" alt="" />       
</div>  
<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">                      
[INSERT EMBED CODE FROM YOUTUBE]
</div>

Comment: Its not perfect, but it works :)